# Conditional cumulative sum in Python/Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, ipython

Consider my dataframe, `df`:

```
data  data_binary  sum_data
  2       1            1
  5       0            0
  1       1            1
  4       1            2
  3       1            3
  10      0            0
  7       0            0
  3       1            1
```

How can I calculate the cumulative sum of `data_binary` within groups of contiguous `1` values?

The first group of `1`'s had a single `1` and `sum_data` has only a `1`.  However, the second group of `1`'s has 3 `1`'s and `sum_data` is `[1, 2, 3]`.

I've tried using `np.where(df['data_binary'] == 1, df['data_binary'].cumsum(), 0)`, but that returns

```
array([1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 5])
```

Which is not what I want.

Comment: What have you tried and what is your requirement? Your question is not clear. Edit it.

Comment: I wanna calculate sum_data using data columns.

Comment: still not a clue what result you want and what you have tried that does not work.

Answer (score 21):

You want to take the cumulative sum of `data_binary` and subtract the most recent cumulative sum where `data_binary` was zero.

```
b = df.data_binary
c = b.cumsum()
c.sub(c.mask(b != 0).ffill(), fill_value=0).astype(int)
```

#### Output

```
0    1
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    0
6    0
7    1
Name: data_binary, dtype: int64
```

---

***Explanation***

Let's start by looking at each step side by side

```
cols = ['data_binary', 'cumulative_sum', 'nan_non_zero', 'forward_fill', 'final_result']
print(pd.concat([
        b, c,
        c.mask(b != 0),
        c.mask(b != 0).ffill(),
        c.sub(c.mask(b != 0).ffill(), fill_value=0).astype(int)
    ], axis=1, keys=cols))
```

#### Output

```
data_binary  cumulative_sum  nan_non_zero  forward_fill  final_result
0            1               1             NaN           NaN             1
1            0               1             1.0           1.0             0
2            1               2             NaN           1.0             1
3            1               3             NaN           1.0             2
4            1               4             NaN           1.0             3
5            0               4             4.0           4.0             0
6            0               4             4.0           4.0             0
7            1               5             NaN           4.0             1
```

The problem with `cumulative_sum` is that the rows where `data_binary` is zero, do not reset the sum.  And that is the motivation for this solution.  How do we "reset" the sum when `data_binary` is zero?  Easy!  I slice the cumulative sum where `data_binary` is zero and forward fill the values.  When I take the difference between this and the cumulative sum, I've effectively reset the sum.

Comment: Very interesting solution. How could this be applied along rows? (axis=1) I am trying without any success.

Comment: The number of columns (6) in the output for the second part does not seem to match the number of column headers (5). Or in other words, the last column seems to be missing a column header.

Answer (score 9):

I think you can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) by `Series`, where first compare the next value by the [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed column if not equal (`!=`) and then create groups by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html). Last, replace `0` by column `data_binary` with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
print (df.data_binary.ne(df.data_binary.shift()).cumsum())
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    3
4    3
5    4
6    4
7    5
Name: data_binary, dtype: int32

df['sum_data1'] = df.data_binary.groupby(df.data_binary.ne(df.data_binary.shift()).cumsum())
                                .cumsum()
df['sum_data1'] = df['sum_data1'].mask(df.data_binary == 0, 0)
print (df)
   data  data_binary  sum_data  sum_data1
0     2            1         1          1
1     5            0         0          0
2     1            1         1          1
3     4            1         2          2
4     3            1         3          3
5    10            0         0          0
6     7            0         0          0
7     3            1         1          1
```

Comment: You now have maverick hat!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the excellent [piRSquared's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41423048/6332373) in just one single command:

```py
df['sum_data'] = df[['data_binary']].apply(
    lambda x: x.cumsum().sub(x.cumsum().mask(x != 0).ffill(), fill_value=0).astype(int), 
    axis=0)
```

Note that the double squared bracket on the right hand side is necessary to make a one-column DataFrame instead of a Series in order to use `apply` with the `axis` argument (which is not available when `apply` is used on Series).