# Pandas: cumulative sum with conditional subtraction

Tags: python, pandas, finance

Consider a pandas dataframe like:

```py
>> df

date_time            op_type  price  volume
01-01-1970 9:30:01     ASK     100    1800 
01-01-1970 9:30:25     ASK      90    1000      
01-01-1970 9:30:28     BID      90     900
01-01-1970 9:30:28    TRADE     90     900
01-01-1970 9:31:01     BID      80     500
01-01-1970 9:31:09     ASK      80     100
01-01-1970 9:31:09    TRADE     80     100
```

I would like to do three calculations: *i)* the cumulative sum of the volume for `op_type == "ASK"` rows; *ii)* the cumulative sum of the volume for `op_type == "BID"` rows; and *iii)* the sum of the previous two volumes.

That is simple enough, but there is a condition for `op_type == "TRADE"` operations:

1. Whenever there is a `TRADE` operation whose `price` matches the `price` on a `BID` operation, I would like to subtract that `TRADE` operation's volume from the cumulative `BID` volume.
2. Whenever there is a `TRADE` operation whose `price` matches the `price` on an `ASK` operation, I would like to subtract that `TRADE` operation's volume from the cumulative `ASK` volume.

The output I'm looking for is:

```py
>> df

date_time            op_type  price  volume  ASK_vol  BID_vol  BIDASK_vol
01-01-1970 9:30:01     ASK     100    1800    1800       0        1800
01-01-1970 9:30:25     ASK      90    1000    2800       0        2800
01-01-1970 9:30:28     BID      90     900    2800      900       3700
01-01-1970 9:30:28    TRADE     90     900    2800       0        2800
01-01-1970 9:31:01     BID      80     500    2800      500       3300
01-01-1970 9:31:09     ASK      80     100    2900      500       3400
01-01-1970 9:31:09    TRADE     80     100    2800      500       3300
```

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41420822/python-pandas-conditional-cumulative-sum) but I'm not sure how to incorporate the conditional subtraction to that answer. I would greatly appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: in the `ASK_vol` shouldn't that last value be 2800?

Comment: You're right, I'll make an edit, thank you so much for your answer

Comment: consider up-voting & accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, this is what you need.

```
a= np.where(df['op_type'] == 'ASK',df.volume,0)
b= np.where(df['op_type'] == 'BID',df.volume,0)
a_t = (np.where(df['op_type'] == 'TRADE',
          (np.where(df['op_type'].shift(1) == 'ASK',
                    (np.where(df['volume']==df['volume'].shift(1),-df.volume,0)),0)),0))
b_t = (np.where(df['op_type'] == 'TRADE',
          (np.where(df['op_type'].shift(1) == 'BID',
                    (np.where(df['volume']==df['volume'].shift(1),-df.volume,0)),0)),0))
df['ASK_vol']=(np.where(a_t!=0,a_t,a)).cumsum()
df['BID_vol']=(np.where(b_t!=0,b_t,b)).cumsum()
df['BIDASK_vol']= df['ASK_vol']+df['BID_vol']
```

**output**

```
           date_time    op_type     price   volume  ASK_vol BID_vol BIDASK_vol
01-01-1970  9:30:01     ASK         100     1800    1800    0       1800
01-01-1970  9:30:25     ASK         90      1000    2800    0       2800
01-01-1970  9:30:28     BID         90      900     2800    900     3700
01-01-1970  9:30:28     TRADE       90      900     2800    0       2800
01-01-1970  9:31:01     BID         80      500     2800    500     3300
01-01-1970  9:31:09     ASK         80      100     2900    500     3400
01-01-1970  9:31:09     TRADE       80      100     2800    500     3300
```

Comment: Just a small observation, in lines 5 and 8 of your answer the condition `df['volume']==df['volume'].shift(1)` within the last `np.where()` should be `df['price']==df['price'].shift(1)`

Comment: oh! ok. I thought we were looking for matching volumes. But in-fact we are looking for matching prices. Good to know that you figured that out.