# pandas frame cumulative sum conditioned

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

Is there a way to cumsum values in column based on the value of another column but after the condition is no more respected, resetting the cumsum? In the below image, the conditioning factor is on 'Rbin' being equal to one.

[image]

```
random_data_frame = pandas.DataFrame()
random_data_frame['Rbin'] = [0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0]
random_data_frame['Rmomentum'] = [-0.07,0.03,0.06,0.005,-0.008,-0.8,0.8,-0.5]
```

Comment: maybe but we cant test since the data is an [image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) which is not reproducible:(

Comment: I though it was very easily reproducible. I left an pandas dataframe as example to compute last column I have illustrated in the image

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41420822/python-pandas-conditional-cumulative-sum/41423048 answer number 2 has your code.  Just adapt that and put it in your version.

Comment: @PaulBrennan yeah, I saw that answer too, but the difficoult was on the idea on forming the column for applying the groupby cumsum function. Anyway, thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an ad-hoc index to identify continuous sequences of `Rbin` values, then use `groupby` and `cumsum` on those sequences and set to `np.nan` values of the cumulative sum where `Rbin` is zero.

```py
random_data_frame['new_id'] = (random_data_frame.Rbin.diff() != 0).cumsum()
random_data_frame['cumulative_sum'] = random_data_frame.groupby('new_id')['Rmomentum'].cumsum().reset_index()['Rmomentum']
random_data_frame.loc[random_data_frame.Rbin == 0, 'cumulative_sum'] = np.nan
```

This is the result on your example:

```sh
   Rbin  Rmomentum  new_id  cumulative_sum
0     0     -0.070       1             NaN
1     1      0.030       2           0.030
2     1      0.060       2           0.090
3     1      0.005       2           0.095
4     0     -0.008       3             NaN
5     0     -0.800       3             NaN
6     1      0.800       4           0.800
7     0     -0.500       5             NaN
```

A compressed version is:

```py
random_data_frame['cumulative_sum'] = np.where(
    random_data_frame.Rbin == 0,
    np.nan,
    random_data_frame.groupby((random_data_frame.Rbin.diff() != 0).cumsum())['Rmomentum'].cumsum().reset_index()['Rmomentum']
)
```