# cumulative sum based on conditions of 2 neighboring colum

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

Apologies, I'm a newbie to coding/pandas/python.

I am trying to sum the column only if there is a "1" located in the "buy" and "sell" neighboring columns

| Date | Buy | Sell | Value | Cumulative Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 |  |  | 1 |  |
| 01/02/2023 | 1 |  | 5 | 5 |
| 01/03/23 |  |  | 1 | 6 |
| 01/04/23 |  |  | 1 | 7 |
| 01/05/23 |  | 1 | 1 | 8 |
| 01/06/23 |  |  | 5 |  |

I saw that there is a formula called **cumsum(axis=None, skipna=True, *args, **kwargs),** that might be able to do this.  but unfortunately, I'm not too sure how to include the conditional on this based on the **buy** and **sell** columns

I'm not sure how to do this with pandas formulas.  Also would i maybe need to utilze a loop for this?

Any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Loops should almost always avoided in Pandas and are almost always never needed. Please provide data and expected output as your requirement is not clear (there are no "buy" and "sell" neighboring" values in your example data).

Comment: Is the requirement to cumsum between rows where buy = 1 and sell = 1?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas frame cumulative sum conditioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65971136/pandas-frame-cumulative-sum-conditioned)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid loops.  I think this is what you are looking for:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
                    'date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-05', '2023-01-06', '2023-01-07', '2023-01-08', '2023-01-09', '2023-01-10', '2023-01-11', '2023-01-12'], 
                    'buy': [None,1,None,None,None,None,None,1,None,None,None,None],
                    'sell':[None,None,None,None,1,None,None,None,None,None,1,None],
                    'value':[1,5,1,1,1,5,1,5,1,1,1,5]
                    }
                  )

# make sell negative so it can be discerned from buy
df1['sell'] = df1['sell'] * -1
        
print(df1)
          date  buy  sell  value
0   2023-01-01  NaN   NaN      1
1   2023-01-02  1.0   NaN      5
2   2023-01-03  NaN   NaN      1
3   2023-01-04  NaN   NaN      1
4   2023-01-05  NaN  -1.0      1
5   2023-01-06  NaN   NaN      5
6   2023-01-07  NaN   NaN      1
7   2023-01-08  1.0   NaN      5
8   2023-01-09  NaN   NaN      1
9   2023-01-10  NaN   NaN      1
10  2023-01-11  NaN  -1.0      1
11  2023-01-12  NaN   NaN      5
        
# create 'buysell' column which is combination of 'buy' and 'sell' columns
        
df1['buysell'] = df1['buy'].combine_first(df1['sell'])
        
# use ffill() to fill buysell from 1 until it is not 1
df1.loc[df1['buysell'].ffill() == 1, 'buysell'] = 1
        
        
# create a mask for where 'buysell' is not NaN
mask = ~df1['buysell'].isna()
            
# use the mask to create a 'buysellvalue' column with the contents of 'value' column for rows where the mask is true
df1.loc[mask, 'buysellvalue'] = df1.loc[mask, 'value']
            
# use cumsum()
df1['cumbuysellvalue'] = df1['buysellvalue'].cumsum()
            
print(df1)
          date  buy  sell  value  buysell  buysellval  cumbuysellval
0   2023-01-01  NaN   NaN      1      NaN         NaN            NaN
1   2023-01-02  1.0   NaN      5      1.0         5.0            5.0
2   2023-01-03  NaN   NaN      1      1.0         1.0            6.0
3   2023-01-04  NaN   NaN      1      1.0         1.0            7.0
4   2023-01-05  NaN  -1.0      1     -1.0         1.0            8.0
5   2023-01-06  NaN   NaN      5      NaN         NaN            NaN
6   2023-01-07  NaN   NaN      1      NaN         NaN            NaN
7   2023-01-08  1.0   NaN      5      1.0         5.0           13.0
8   2023-01-09  NaN   NaN      1      1.0         1.0           14.0
9   2023-01-10  NaN   NaN      1      1.0         1.0           15.0
10  2023-01-11  NaN  -1.0      1     -1.0         1.0           16.0
11  2023-01-12  NaN   NaN      5      NaN         NaN            NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you intend to do a cumsum between a pair of Buy and Sell.
We can create different groups between pair of buy/sell and then do the cumsum for these groups.
To do the groupby, we can create a temporary buysellgroup column which will help us to do groupby between multiple pair of buy/sell.

Suppose we have below table:

[image]

We can then create a buy_sell_group between each pair of buy/sell cell where value = 1.0

```
buy_sell_group = [np.nan for _ in range(len(df))]
i = 1
for b,s in zip(df.loc[df.buy == 1.0].index, df.loc[df.sell == 1.0].index):
    buy_sell_group[b:s+1] = [i] * (s+1-b)
    i += 1
df['buy_sell_group'] = buy_sell_group
```

This results in below dataframe

[image]

We can then do groupby on 'buy_sell_group' column and do a cumsum on 'value' column

```
df['cumsum'] = df.groupby('buy_sell_group')['value'].cumsum()
df = df.drop('buy_sell_group', axis=1)
```

Final dataframe

[image]

Please note that above implementation assumes that

- each buy=1, will have a corresponding sell=1, and
- each buy/sell pair will not have any other buy/sell = 1 value in between

Comment: greatly apprecaited!  this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you for the loop solution you have provided!  This will defintely help me out with my learning!